# How to repeat object properties in angular ui-select-choices?

Tags: angularjs, object, angular-ui-select

I have an object as

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
}
```

How will repeat this in `ui-select-choices`? I tried a few things but nothing worked as

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedChoice" theme="select2">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'select_product' | translate}}" allow-clear="true">
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="key as (key, value) in (productList | filter: $select.search)">
        <span>{{::key}}</span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="product.key as (key, product) in productList | filter: {'value':$select.search}">
    <span ng-bind-html="product.value"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

[Angular UI Select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki) iterates over objects kinda this way: during iterating for each pair `(key, value)` instead of accessing the value directly, an object (it's named `product` in my code above) is created that consists of two properties named `key` and `value`, where `key` is an actual key of the initial object, `value` is a value for the key. This object should be used to access a real value.

For example, for the following initial data object

```
{
    key1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John'
    },
    key2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Alex'
    }
}
```

on the first iteration such object will be created:

```
{
    key: 'key1',
    value: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John'
    }
}
```

For your data object, the following object will be created on the first iteration (`product`):

```
{
    key: 'key1',
    value: 'value1'
}
```